# How to choose what gets printed out in custom view form?

Tags: custom-form, printing

Hi Everyone I have a custom view form that I created with SharePoint designer and added it by adding a content editor webpart in the default edit view form.

From there I created a Print Button which would print my form. It is printing everything on the form, but I want I only want to print a section from the entire form.

This is my view form and I don't want the green section to print up top. or the bottem create and modified section..

How would I go about this? I was thinking about creating a button which will lead to a print form that I can customize on what I want to print, would that work?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using browser developer tool from the items you want to eliminate from Print out. Then during the Print button click you can open up the print page and pass a query string something like

```
http://url/pagetoprint.aspx?IsPrint=1
```

Now in that page, add a JavaScript to read the QueryString, and if it is present then hide those elements using jQuery

```
$('#itemtohide').hide();
```

Then invoke the print dialog

```
window.print();
```

Comment: Where would I put the code? currently I have this in my viewform....   <input onclick="window.print();return" type="button" value="Print Form"/>

Comment: anyone knows about this?

Comment: You should create a new page ex:`pagetoprint.aspx` and add the same list view. Then edit that page and handle `window.load or document.ready` event using JavaScript. In that event `hide` the elements you don't want show.

Comment: I am not using .net, can this be done through HTML?

Comment: Yes. Do you know how to create a new page in SharePoint? That is what I said above. The other events can be setup using JavaScript by editing the page in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: yes when I create a new page, only put the fields that I want to print out first correct?

Comment: Yes. You can create a similar page with the same list view etc.

Comment: I created a html page, it is inside SITE Assets. Now how do I insert into my sharepoint site?